# swift presentViewController programmatically finds nil in destinationVC VDL

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, presentviewcontroller

Trying to solidify my knowledge by understanding lines of code at a basic level.

I've tweaked my app to use ViewController(VC)2 as initial VC instead of VC1.

I'm practicing populating this VC2 entirely by code. When coding a UIButton to segue into VC1, my console outputs "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" (lldb). and thread 1 points to  VC1 viewDidLoad (VDL) where I've set some properties

VC1

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    P1Chip.hidden = true; P2Chip.hidden = true; P3Chip.hidden = true; P4Chip.hidden = true; P5Chip.hidden = true; P6Chip.hidden = true; P7Chip.hidden = true; P8Chip.hidden = true; P9Chip.hidden = true


etc
```

This VC1 was not having any problems with VDL when it was the initial VC.

method to populate VC2

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class VC2: UIViewController {
    let home:UIButton! = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(10,10,15,15)) as UIButton


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        home.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.4, green: 0.6, blue: 0, alpha: 1)
        home.setTitle("home", forState: .Normal)
        home.addTarget(self, action: "home:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
        view.addSubview(home)     
    }

    func home(sender:UIButton!) {
        self.presentViewController((VC1() as UIViewController), animated: true, completion: nil)

    }    
}
```

Any idea what I'm missing?

[image]

[image]

NOTE: btw VC2 is actually called Settings in my project

Comment: Using your VC2 code, I have no problems transitioning to another ViewController. Where does the error point at?

Comment: points at VC1's VDL `P1Chip...~`

Comment: can you show us more of the code in VC1? I don't see any optionals in your viewDidLoad.

Comment: Have you considered arrays...?

Comment: considered...meaning using them to have cleaner code? or that maybe this error is caused by or the misuse of an array?

Comment: No matter the changes to my VC1 VDL it points to the first line of code in VDL that has an reference to a var in VC1

Comment: Are your `P1Chip` variables IBOutlets? If they are and you made VC1 in storyboard then instantiating a VC1 object via `VC1()` won't instantiate what you see in the storyboard, resulting in a nil for any IBOutlets. It would certainly help to see the declaration of your `P1Chip` variables in your VC1 class.

Comment: This is absolutely the case `@IBOutlet weak var P1Chip: UIImageView!` all VC1 Objects are storyboard instantiated. so do I have to call VC1 (which was fully made in storyboard) from VC2(fully programmatical) using a different method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So when instantiating a VC (storyboard-created), first we need to route our call through the UIStoryboard by name

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
```

then instantiate a VC using the Storyboard ID of our storyboard setup VC

```
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("VC1") as VC1    //VC1 refers to destinationVC source file and "VC1" refers to destinationVC Storyboard ID
```

Then we can present VC using

```
self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

This will import all of destinationVC's objects with their IBOutlet references.